# how to pass a value from javascript variable to c# variable in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

Here i have a value in javascript variable and i need to pass this value to c# variable.How to pass this value while loading that cshtml file?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str="value"; 
</script>
```

in razor view

```
var a=str; //c#
```

Any suggestion??

Comment: What do you want to do with that variable? Perhaps there's a different way of doing it.

Comment: Explain your actual problem including the relevant code parts (keep em short!), there probably is a way to achieve the result in some fashion

Comment: It is not possible, find other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is **You can't**

You wont be able to pass/convert JavaScript variable to a Razor variable. **Razor variable is handled by Razor engine** where as **JavaScript on the other hand is a client side language running on the client.**

Razor is a view engine used by the ASP.NET MVC framework running on the server to produce some HTML template.

Comment: i dont want to convert that variable..i just need to pass that value "value" to c# variable a

Comment: @bala3569, Still answer is you can't. However you can submits its value to controller action